# Javascript XSLT Transformation returning null

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I'm using JavaScript to apply a xslt transformation to a xml file to return a json object in a specific format.

I'm using the following code to test the process:

```
var xml = loadDoc("my.xml"); //custom function that loads the xml and xsl docs these are working
var xsl = loadDoc("my.xsl");

var processor = new XSLTProcessor();
processor.importStylesheet(xsl);
var result = processor.transformToDocument(xml);

console.log(result);
```

I've tested the code with a couple of very simple xml and xsl files with success however the console log outputs a null when I'm testing it with the xsl document and xml I'm supposed to use, they were not prepared by me and I have very little experience with xslt transformations.

I've tested those files using a couple of online tools and they worked on a couple of them but others were unable to perform the transformation. (http://xslttest.appspot.com/ this can run the transformation without a problem but not this one http://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html)

Comment: Does the stylesheet use XSLT `version="2.0"`? Browsers only support version 1.0. What happens when you try http://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html, do you get any error message? Can you post the stylesheet code or a link to it?

Comment: It does not use versio 2.0. Using that tool I get "Unable to perform XSL transformation on your XML file. null".

Here is the file I'm using: http://test53.comlu.com/file.xsl

Answer (score 1):

That stylesheet uses XSLT 2.0 features like `xsl:function` so don't expect any XSLT 1.0 processor like the one in browsers to be able to execute that code.